# Include ANY, ALL, or NOT options with tag searches

Tags: forms, tags

I have a website where people can organize their documents using tags. Tags might include Work, Games, ToDo, ForKids, Pictures, Cooking, Knitting, Crochet, Beginner, etc.

Users can currently search for documents with one or more selected tags. Tags are listed like buttons and there is an All/Any option that decides whether the filtered documents must have ALL tags (Crafts that are ForKids) or ANY tag (Crochet or Knitting).

Radio button: All / Any

Work

Games

ToDo

You select a tag by clicking/tapping it (it changes color), and then click Search. You can select more than one tag.

The question is how to include a NOT choice. For example, someone might want to search for Games that are not ForKids. Or documents that are Knitting or Crochet, but not Beginner.

**Three-way toggle**

I have seen one solution where they provided a three-way toggle button (Not, neutral, Include) like so:

Toggle-button Work

Toggle-button Games

I don't like that the clickable area becomes so small, fitting 3 choices onto a small button and leaving less room for the text.

**Advanced menu with text**

Google's advanced search is text-based, where you can enter words to include or words not to include into a form with labels like "any of these words", "None of these words"

I'm trying to keep it more click-based. I also do *not* need the full freedom of Google's searches: Must have (A and B) or C, but not D.

I am open to an advanced search option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Hovering over buttons to find option to YES a tag or NO a tag]

You can provide user an option of selecting (YES) or rejecting (NO) a tag via a on-hover overlay. Based on color, it would be quite apparent about the selection of a tag.

Similarly, on selecting radio button "ALL", all the tag would turn green. the user can still say No to a tag via hover overlay.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: That's a pretty interesting way of doing it. It requires 2 clicks every time, which would be extra clicks. NOT will be used a lot less

Comment: I understand you are considering 2clicks as the first to get the overlay and second to click the green or red icon. My proposal was actually just one click to select a tag since you get the overlay on hovering the button. So technically, still only one click to select a tag. Please correct me if I my understanding is wrong

Comment: Ah, I see. Gotcha

Comment: @user295469: Please mark my answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark below the voting icons if this answers your question